# can't UPDATE mysql when IS NULL

Tags: mysql, select

When I run the following MYSQL SELECT query, it returns a bunch of records:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = 'country' 
AND `meta_value` IS NULL
```

When I run this UPDATE query, it works and changes a bunch of records

```
UPDATE
    `wp_usermeta`
SET
    `meta_value` = 'xxx'
WHERE
    `meta_key` = 'country' AND `meta_value` = 'fr'
```

The same applies and it changes records if the condition is this:

```
WHERE
    `meta_key` = 'country' AND `meta_value` IS NOT NULL
```

But... when I try to run the following - which is the one I'm after - it cannot find any records at all:

```
UPDATE
    `wp_usermeta`
SET
    `meta_value` = 'xxx'
WHERE
    `meta_key` = 'country' AND `meta_value` IS NULL
```

For some reason, the IS NULL just won't work with this. I know there are NULL records because the first SELECT query found them; why won't it work with UPDATE though?

Comment: What's your indication that it does not find any records?

Comment: Beware that MySQL doesn't report matching rows as *updated* when no update is actually done (e.g., the server detects that new values are identical to existing ones). In any case we really need more information to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Couldn't be the case here because `meta_value` is updated.

Comment: *For some reason, the IS NULL just won't work with this.* Specify this reason - it looks like something impossible.

Comment: @GSerg You're right. I hadn't dug into the details.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

How very weird. It seems that when I tried SIMULATE QUERY in phpMyAdmin then with IS NULL it reported nothing found to update. (SIMULATE QUERY with the other values showed a possible result.)

But when I ran the actual query it actually did update a whole bunch of rows.

So it *appears* to be to do with and UPDATE SIMULATE QUERY not displaying possible results with IS NULL.